# Rails two step signup with devise - Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, user-registration

I am trying to set-up a two step signup process using Devise in Rails and followed this [tutorial by Claudio Marai](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/05/two-step-signup-with-devise/).
When I enter the e-mail address in the form (first step), I get an error telling me there was a routing error and that it couldn't find `RegistrationsController`

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-03 22:50:59 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RegistrationsController):
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
  .
  .
  .
```

I figured this was due to the presence of `:registrations => "registrations"` in my `routes.rb file` as described in the first step of [the tutorial](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/05/two-step-signup-with-devise/).  I then tried two alternatives which both resulted in the same error.  First, I removed the `:registrations => "registrations"` from the `routes.rb file`.  When that didn't work, I re-inserted the line and added a `registrations_controller.rb` to the `controllers` directory which looked like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

I figured the two options would have the same effect - but - I tried them anyway.

The error I got was the following:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-03 22:47:29 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"ttPBRPRLVzPBHcDDKRJbimv0Yp/egdK5qBkIvBTL4Ig=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com"}, "x"=>"0", "y"=>"0"}
   (0.6ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@email.com' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@email.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = '8tA1jakpAXNK4Piz7J6R' LIMIT 1
  SQL (14.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "fb_id", "fb_token", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["confirmation_sent_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 22:47:30 EDT -04:00], ["confirmation_token", "8tA1jakpAXNK4Piz7J6R"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 22:47:30 EDT -04:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "test@email.com"], ["encrypted_password", nil], ["fb_id", nil], ["fb_token", nil], ["first_name", nil], ["last_name", nil], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["state", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 22:47:30 EDT -04:00]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "fb_id", "fb_token", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 441ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "fb_id", "fb_token", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)):
  sqlite3 (1.3.5) lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
  sqlite3 (1.3.5) lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
  sqlite3 (1.3.5) lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
  sqlite3 (1.3.5) lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
  .
  .
  .
```

The above error has me really confused!

With the same form, when I add the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields, then things proceed smoothly - the user account is created and a confirmation email is sent to the user with the confirmation link.

I would appreciate any help regarding this - thanks!  I am using `Ruby 1.9.3-p125` and `Rails 3.2.1`

Comment: That tutorial seems kinda thorough, are you sure you didn't miss anything? Namely, overriding the `password_required?` method inside Devise's module?

Comment: @Ashitaka As you might imagine, I have gone through the tutorial 20 times already! :P  I do have the `password_required?` method in one of the `initializer` files as explained by the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't due to Rails validation, it's due to a violation of a database constraint.

More than likely, if your users table migration was generated by Devise, then the schema includes this:

```
"encrypted_password" varchar(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

The SQL that's causing the ConstraintException includes this (elided for readability):

```
SQL (14.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" (..., "encrypted_password", ...) VALUES (..., ?, ...)  [..., ["encrypted_password", nil], ...]
```

So, something is telling your database adapter to set `encrypted_password = nil`.

You should be able to circumvent it either be running a migration that removes the NOT NULL constraint on the `encrypted_password`, or do as you've done, pass in an `encrypted_password`, but just make sure it's empty in the first step, but present in the second step.

Comment: Wow - great catch!  That worked!
I am surprised the tutorial didn't talk about this?! :o